# Chrome crashes all the time

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10

I updated my windows 8.1 to windows 10 recently. Everything is fine except for Chrome. Chrome opens and crashes. How many times I reinstall, the problem remains the same. Do I need to wait for chrome update or is there a solution for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try running it in compatibility mode? I just upgraded to win 10 as well and haven't had this issue with chrome, maybe if you set the compatibility level to windows 8 or windows 7 it'll work.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but, still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

- run "cmd" as Administrator (search "cmd", right mouse-click, run as Administrator)

  - type "netsh.exe winsock reset", then reboot computer

After the reboot chrome started to work for me again. I found that in some forum and i just tried it out, since running in windows 8 compatibility modus did not work for me. Neither Chrome Canary (unstable chrome), which was constantly crashing.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same issue from past few days(almost a month). Following helped me to get my chrome work well...

1. Close chrome.
2. Open Windows Explorer and go to following folder path: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
3. Delete the file named “Local State” in that path
4. Also rename a folder named "Default" to "Default.old"
5. Thats it your chrome works well.
6. Happy browsing.
7. List item

You can find more details in the follwing link. http://www.kitwall.com/wallalert/45d3hx4u6xwh22ckvxz35ayw5/=014ggvbnq6j5x